# XCode how to fix removed files from project. Erro Missing file

Tags: xcode

I remove some files from project and now then project builds i see next picture

[image]

And i use SVN as version control.

Comment: Are you using any subversion softwares? I faced this while using Cornerstone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mske sure that you did what follows:

- in the *build rules* tab of the project settings, under *Compile files*, you have removed the references to the deleted files
- still in *build rules*, under *Resource bundle", you removed any reference to the deleted resource files (eg images)
- you cleaned the project (CMD + Shift + K)

Comment: I did all the above but the missing file issues are still not resolving! Any other solution?